# How to fire an event on error in jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have jquery validator running and the page is very long, so I want the page to scroll up to the top because I display errors on the very top of the page above the form, does anyone know where I can put the code for the animation so it fires when the form has errors?

Comment: Can you post the code you have now to call the validation?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`invalidHandler` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) for the exact case you want, like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: { ... rules here ... }
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);      
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it scroll to the element that was invalid in particular? So if you had a huge form and in the middle somewhere there was the error? On phones this is important since I can scroll to the top but the error might not be there in particular.

Answer (score 8):

The same as @Nick suggested, but to use after plugin initialization:

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {

});
```

Its the same that happens internally when the plugin initializes. [Source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/63cb473c211c2ecf30abf0b9c432ad7c35dc5778/src/core.js#L387).

Comment: this is a lifesaver .. except that for me it's firing 3 times on the same validation failure.

Comment: @Damon not sure why that happens

Comment: @damon probably because you have 3 forms?