# Scroll to particular error with jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I found a good reference here for how to handle errors and scroll ([How to fire an event on error in jquery validator plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885346/how-to-fire-an-event-on-error-in-jquery-validator-plugin)), but I don't understand how to scroll to a particular error.  Lets say I had 20 elements that errors could occur on and your on a mobile device, right now if there is an error I can scroll to the top, but that might not be where the error is!

I disabled focusInvalid because that brought up the keyboard on mobile in an obtrusive way and did not scroll to the element anyways.

Is there a way to do this with the plugin or any custom code?

This is my invalid handler right now.

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
            },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrolling to the error is not part of this plugin.  You'll have to use one of the built-in callback functions with your own animation code...

- `invalidHandler` does not give you access to the individual error messages.  It simply fires when you click the submit button on an invalid form.  Therefore, you cannot use this option to scroll to individual fields.
- `showErrors` will give you access to the individual error messages and elements.  However, you'll have to figure out which one you want to scroll to since all of the pending errors are listed here at once.  Code below will scroll to first element with an error (highest on the form).

  ```
  showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        // errorList[0].element; // <- index "0" is the first element with an error

        if (typeof errorList[0] != "undefined") {
            var position = $(errorList[0].element).position().top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: position
            }, 300);
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors(); // keep error messages next to each input element   
  }
  ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/tvr6f9j1/1/**

Comment: for some reason this didn't work on my code, but I'm going to play around with this more, will get back to you as soon as I can, thank you for your answer! If I can't figure it out soon, I'll post in my question more details, maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok your code works, but what happens is the error messages don't go away after you typed the answer correctly anymore.  The only way to make it go away is to hit submit again on the button.  None the less it did answer the scrolling question but created another bug in the process.  Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan, the primary purpose of `showErrors` is to create an error summary box.  This function then over-rides the default validation triggers like `onfocusout`, which is why it makes `this.defaultShowErrors();` available to you.  The developer probably figured dynamically removing the error messages while the summary list stays static until the next submit, didn't make sense.  Unfortunately, I can think of no other suitable location to trigger the scroll animation where you'll still have access to the error list.

Comment: I see, I noticed some other errors as well (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined), so I probably have to write my own functions to handle onfocusout then I take it?

Comment: I figured out how to fix the error I was getting, if you modiy the code you gave to put this ............. if(typeof errorList[0] != "undefined"){
       var position = $(errorList[0].element).position().top;
       console.log("errorPos="+position);
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: position - 76 - 20}, 300);
      }........ then it works! (less what I put about 76-20, the key here is the undefined check when there is no errors anymore.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan, Ok, good deal then.  I updated my answer with your correction.

Comment: It's better to replace `position()` to `offset()` as `position()` is relative to the nearest parent's element, instead of the document/page.

Comment: @PhillipQuinlan, maybe so, but that's not really the point.  The point is how to trigger some action when the plugin fires an error message... insert whatever scrolling method or animation you wish.